# When and how does Optaplanner evaluate rules?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

We are just getting our heads around using Optaplanner for a project.  We have a very simple solution setup as per following:

```
Job -> PlanningEntity, PlanningVariable=Resource from resourcesList
Resource -> POJO
Solution
   - List<Job> PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
   - List<Resource> ProblemFactCollectionProperty, resourcesList
```

We have setup some rules for testing. The first rule is simply to say, don't assign more than three Jobs to a Resource:

```
rule "noMoreThan3JobsPerResource"
    when
        $resource : Resource()
        $totalJobsOnResource : Number(intValue > 3) from accumulate (
            Job(
                resource == $resource,
                $count : 1),
                sum($count)
            )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 3 - $totalJobsOnResource.intValue());
end
```

What we want to understand is HOW and WHEN the drools rules are evaluated.  For example, if we add these two rules:

```
rule "logWhenResource"
    when
        $resource: Resource()
    then
        System.out.println("RESOURCE encountered");
end
rule "logWhenJob"
    when
        $job : Job()
    then
        System.out.println("JOB encountered");
end
```

We get "JOB encountered" in the log, but never "RESOURCE encountered". And yet, our first rule has $resource : Resource() in the when? Does optaplanner fire a rule when a job is placed (in our example)? We are just a bit unclear on why logWhenResource doesn't fire, but noMoreThan3JobsPerResource does (when they both try and 'match' a Resource object? Is Resource the resource that a job has been moved to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some discussions on IRC, (and a lot of patient help from Geoffrey!), hopefully the following will serve as a helper for other people.

**1. Turn Logging on**

First off, make sure you turn on trace logging for the Optaplanner package (and maybe turn it off for drools). This really helps as it shows *exactly* when optaplanner is triggering score calculations. It also shows the candidate score calculation:

```
Move index (0), score (-3init/-2hard/0medium/0soft), move (Job 7 {null -> Resource 1}).
```

in addition to the final step selection:

```
CH step (6), time spent (110), score (-3init/-2hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (2), picked move (Job 7 {null -> Resource 1}).
```

You can also log in your "then" part of Rules, by doing something like:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.optaplanner").debug("...);
```

This makes sure it gets logged in the right order as Logging vs println can be asynchronous and things may not be in time ascending order.

**2. Understand when Optaplanner calculates scores, and when it doesn't**

This is a pretty useful summary of the 'event loop' of optaplanner:

```
doMove()
fireAllRules()
undoMove()
doMove()
fireAllRules()
undoMove()
doStep()
doMove()
fireAllRules()
undoMove() ...
```

etc. One thing that is interesting, as per our chat on IRC is the following:

"Notice that it doesn't do fireAllRules() after an undoMove or after doStep() because it can predict the score". Neat.

**3. FULL_ASSERT**

To check whether you are corrupting the score, turn on FULL_ASSERT.

```
 <environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</environmentMode>
```

This is useful to determine if your score calculation isn't right (ours wasn't).

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `TRACE` logging. It fires all rules (that have changed since last time because it's **incremental calculation**) every time there's a **move** line in that log.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey

I think that my question is more around at a high level, when are rules evaluated? Is it every time a move is considered? In the example above, if we had 2 resources and 10 jobs, would rule 1 fire twice every time a move was considered and ten times for rule 2? Or do the patterns in the rules only select the objects that have moved? E.g if job 7 is moved, would rule 2 fire once (matching only job 2) or 10 times (matching all jobs)?

Comment: Try it out by placing a System.out in the `then` side. But turn on trace logging to clearly see where each fireAllRules() occurs too. It does incremental calculation, so it will fire only that delta.